# Disable validation on p:splitButton click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have `p:splitButton` inside `p:dataTable` as following:

```
<p:splitButton value="Select">
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" action="#{bean.deleteType(type)}" 
        update="@parent,:form" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    <p:menuitem value="Add" action="#{nominee.addType}" 
        update="@parent,:form" icon="ui-icon-plus" />
</p:splitButton>
```

I want to disable form validation when any option is selected from splitButton. I have already tried using `immediate="true"` and `process="@this"` but nothing useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

`immediate="true"` worked in my case on `p:menuitem` instead of `p:splitButton` as following:

```
<p:splitButton value="Select">
    <p:menuitem value="Delete" action="#{bean.deleteType(type)}" 
        update="@parent,:form" icon="ui-icon-close" immediate="true" />
    <p:menuitem value="Add" action="#{nominee.addType}" 
        update="@parent,:form" icon="ui-icon-plus" immediate="true" />
</p:splitButton>
```

Now, the form is not being validated on selecting any option from `p:splitButton` while retaining action defined for `p:menuitem`.